# Convert below mentioned Json String to Dictionary

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

Below mentioned is my JSON String:

```
{
"StoreID": "ABC012",
"BillNo": "A000000001",
"Amount":  "1234.56",
"Auth": 96fc3411-dfa5-4df7-ada8-25b8a58ef1ea
}
```

I am using below mentioned code to convert

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

It is returning nil for the above-mentioned case but is working fine for:

```
{
"StoreID": "BC007",
"BillNo": "M170000351",
"Amount": 1818.96
}
```

I don't know what is the case, error.localizedDescription == The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: ""Auth": 96fc3411-dfa5-4df7-ada8-25b8a58ef1ea" That's not valid JSON, it's missing doubles quotes around the "Auth" values.

Comment: "Auth": 96fc3411-dfa5-4df7-ada8-25b8a58ef1ea <- must be a string with "X"

Answer (score 2):

You first JSON is invalid. You need to put Strings in quotes and the value assigned to `Auth` is a String.

```
{
"StoreID": "ABC012",
"BillNo": "A000000001",
"Amount":  "1234.56",
"Auth": "96fc3411-dfa5-4df7-ada8-25b8a58ef1ea"
}
```

You should always confirm that your JSON is valid if in doubt, [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) is one tool you can use for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need

1-

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let storeID, billNo, amount, auth: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case storeID = "StoreID"
        case billNo = "BillNo"
        case amount = "Amount"
        case auth = "Auth"
    }
}
```

2-

```
{
    "StoreID": "ABC012",
    "BillNo": "A000000001",
    "Amount":  "1234.56",
    "Auth": "96fc3411-dfa5-4df7-ada8-25b8a58ef1ea"
}
```

3-

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> Root? {
  return try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: text.data(using:.utf8)!)
}
```

Comment: If it's `convertToDictionary` custom `Root` return type doesn't suit.

Comment: @user28434 wrong , using a model is always better than dictionaries

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. What if the task requires specifically for dictionary. You may propose to use custom type, but not make it #1 step in this problem solution.

Comment: don't think there is a such case specifically the op seems not try using Codable before

Answer (score 0):

Value `96fc3411-dfa5-4df7-ada8-25b8a58ef1ea` of `Auth` key is not doubleqouted ( `""` ) . So it is not a valid datatype for json format.